# Is there a name for this combinatorial identity?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I found this identity in a textbook that I own but they did not name the identity and I had some trouble finding it online. Does anyone know the name of the identity and if I can find a resource about it online?

$$\sum^n_{k=0}{{n}\choose{k}}\cdot 2^k = 3^n$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This follows immediately from the [binomial theorem:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)

> $(x+y)^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}y^k$

using $x=1$ and $y=2$ yields the result.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I didn't see that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd just like to point out that there is a combinatorial interpretation of this without using the binomial theorem: for a fixed $k$ and for some $n$-set $S$, $\binom{n}{k}2^k$ counts the number of pairs $(A,B)$, where $A \subseteq S, |A|=k$ and $B\subseteq A$. ($\binom{n}{k}$ counts the $A$'s and $2^k$ counts the $B$'s.) Then $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}2^k$ counts all pairs $(A, B)$ such that $B\subseteq A\subseteq S$, with no restrictions on the size of $B$ or the size of $A$. Alternatively, we can consider each element $x$ of $S$, and pick one of three options: $x\in B$ (and consequently, $x \in A$), $x \in A\backslash B$, or $x\in S\backslash A$. This also gives all pairs $(A,B)$ as before, and is counted as $3^n$.